# Validating multiple check boxes with different names to make sure at least 1 is checked

Tags: php, validation, checkbox

I have a PHP form with several check boxes (not groups) with different names that when submitted get sent to an array and emailed. The problem I am having is that I am looking for a way to validate that at least one of the check boxes is checked upon submit. I know how to do one check box or to do check box groups but not this. How can this be done? If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

I am adding the code for the section of the form I am asking about.

```
  <form action="" method="post">



   <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Please Select at least one:
        </legend>
 <p class="style5">Type of Alleged Occurrence:<input name="occurrence" type="hidden"    value="<?php { print 'Type of Occurrence'; }?>"></p>
                            <font size="-1"   face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" align="left">
                            <table style="width: 100%">
                                <tr><td   style="width: 21%; height: 57px;"><strong> Disruption:</strong><br><input name="obscene"   type="checkbox" value="Obscene Language" <?php if(isset($_POST['obscene'])) echo "checked"; ?>><label  id="obscene">Obscene language </label>
                                    </td><td   style="width: 33%; height: 57px;">
                                    <strong> Sexual Harassment:</strong><br><input name="sexharass" type="checkbox" value="Physical" <?php if(isset($_POST['sexharass'])) echo "checked"; ?>  ><label  id="sexharass">Physical </label>&nbsp;<span lang="en-us">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </span>&nbsp;<input name="sexharass" type="checkbox" value="Verbal" <?php if(isset($_POST['sexharass'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label  id="sexharass2">Verbal </label>
```

```
<td  style="width: 21%; height: 57px;"><strong> Altercation:</strong>
<br><input name="altercation1" type="checkbox" value="Verbal" <?php if(isset($_POST['altercation1'])) echo "checked"; ?>><label id="Label3">Verbal</label>

 <input name="altercation1" type="checkbox" value="Physical" <?php   if(isset($_POST['altercation1'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label id="Label4">Physical</label> <br>



                                    <td    style="width: 33%; height: 57px;"><strong>Involved in altercation:</strong><br>



 <input name="altercation2" type="checkbox" value="student/student" <?php if(isset($_POST['altercation2'])) echo "checked"; ?>><label id="Label3">Student/Student </label>


<input name="altercation2" type="checkbox" value="student/faculty-staff" <?php if(isset($_POST['altercation2'])) echo "checked"; ?>><label id="Label4">Student/Faculty-Staff </label>
```

```
<tr><td><strong> Theft/ Damage to Property:</strong><br><input name="property" type="checkbox" value="DACC" <?php if(isset($_POST['property'])) echo "checked"; ?>  ><label  id="property">DACC </label>&nbsp;<span lang="en-us">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" align="left"><input name="property1" type="checkbox" value="Self" <?php if(isset($_POST['property'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label  id="property3">Self </label>



</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
                                    </span><input name="property" type="checkbox" value="Faculty/Staff" <?php if(isset($_POST['property'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label  id="property2">Faculty/Staff </label>




  </td>
   <td><strong> Threat of Harm to Self or Others:</strong><br><input name="harm" type="checkbox" value="Student/Student" <?php if(isset($_POST['harm'])) echo "checked"; ?>  >
<label  id="harm">Student/Student </label>&nbsp;<span lang="en-us">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" align="left"><input name="harm2" type="checkbox" value="Self" <?php if(isset($_POST['harm'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label  id="property2">Self </label>



</font><br>
                                    </span>
            <font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" align="left">
                            <span lang="en-us"><input name="harm1" type="checkbox" value="Student/Faculty-Staff" <?php if(isset($_POST['harm'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label  id="harm3">Student/Faculty-Staff </label>



            &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></font></td></tr>


<tr><td><strong> Drugs/Alcohol:</strong><br><input name="drugs" type="checkbox" value="Under the Influence" <?php if(isset($_POST['drugs'])) echo "checked"; ?>  ><label  id="drugs">Under the Influence </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" align="left"><input name="drugs" type="checkbox" value="Possession" <?php if(isset($_POST['drugs'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label  id="drugs2">Possession </label>



</font>




   </td><td><strong> Other Occurrences:</strong><br><input name="other" type="checkbox" value="Student/Student" <?php if(isset($_POST['other'])) echo "checked"; ?>  ><label  id="other">Trespassing </label>&nbsp;<span lang="en-us">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" align="left"><input name="other" type="checkbox" value="Other" <?php if(isset($_POST['other'])) echo "checked"; ?> ><label  id="other2">Other </label>



</font><br>
                                    </span>
            </td></tr>              </table><p></p>
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you post your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your form structure, you're going to need to use the `isset()` check. Assuming you're **NOT** posting as an array (`<input type='checkbox' name='cb[]' value='x' /><input type='checkbox' name='cb[]' value='x' />...etc`, you can do it this way:

```
<form method='post'...>
<input type='checkbox' name='cb1' value='x' />
<input type='checkbox' name='cb2' value='x' />
</form>
```

validate with...

```
$require_one_of = array('cb1','cb2',...etc); //names of posted checkboxes
$one_set=false;
foreach($require_one_of as $key){
   if(isset($_POST[$key])){
      $one_set=true;
      break;
   }
}
if(!$one_set){
   //error handling
}
```

If you are posting as an array, then you can just check if the array is set:

```
<form method='post'...>
<input type='checkbox' name='cb[]' value='x' />
<input type='checkbox' name='cb[]' value='x' />
</form>
```

validate with

```
<?php
 if(!isset($_POST['cb'])){
   //error handling
}
?>
```

*Note: I'm assuming here that you're using post as for form submission method*

Comment: Yes I am using post as the form method. Thanks Ben I will give this a try!

Comment: ok I added what you suggested to my code and it doesn't throw any errors even when no check boxes are checked, can you look at what I did with what you gave me to see if I did something wrong please? `code`  $require_one_of = array('obscene','altercation1', 'altercation2', 'sexharass', 'property', 'harm', 'drugs', 'other',); //names of posted checkboxes
$one_set=false;
foreach($require_one_of as $key){
   if(isset($_POST[$key])){
      $one_set=true;
      break;
   }
}
if(!$one_set){echo 'please select a type of occurrence';
   //error handling
}
`code`

Comment: A couple of issues: 1) You have a trailing comma in your array definition... should be `array('obscene','altercation1', 'altercation2', 'sexharass', 'property', 'harm', 'drugs', 'other');` and 2) Where is this code in your page? and are you sure that there is no logic that would prevent the loop from being entered... can you post your whole code? Also, add in `print_r($_POST)` at the bottom of the receiving page just to make sure it looks like you expect